# Update data of master tbl based on child tbl data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table tblEMP and tblChild.

In tblEMP, I have two column Empid and salary and in tblEMP salary value is currently null.
In tblChild, I have three column Childid, Empid and salary. whrere empid is from tblEMP.

I have datas as shown in below image[image].

Now I want to update Salary of tblEMP from salary of tblChild with matched EMPID.

For Example tblEMP : EMPID 1's salary would be : 2500 (tblChild ChildId 3)  and

EMPID 2's salary would be : 500 (tblChild ChildId 4) and
EMPID 3's salary would be : 4000 (tblChild ChildId 6).

Thanks

Comment: So your match criteria is the child record with maximum `ChildId` for a given `EMPID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select empid,max(childid) maxid
from child
group by empid)

update emp
set salary = c.salary
from
emp e
inner join cte t on e.empid = t.empid
inner join child c on t.maxid = c.childid
```

Basically, you get the maximum `ChildID` for each `EmpID` and then do 2 joins - first between `Emp` and the CTE based on `EmpId` and then between the CTE and `Child` on the `ChildID`, to get the desired records from the `Child` table.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

```
;with cte
as
(
select childid, empid, salary, 
row_number() over(partition by empid order by empid, childid desc) rno 
from child
)
update emp
    set salary = cte.salary
from cte
where cte.empid = temp.empid
and cte.rno = 1
```

doing row numbering based on empid and updating employee table accodtingly